# Get addresses of a list of coordinates

Tags: angular, firebase, loops, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an angular application where I have a list of places coming from firestore as follow:

```
places =[
          {"id":1, 
           "name": place 1, 
           "latitude": 40.713484, 
           "longitude": -74.006739},
          {"id":2, 
           "name": place 2, 
           "latitude": 40.712801, 
           "longitude": 74.004936},
       .....]
```

And the list goes for about 1000 item, I need to operate a function to get the address of each place and add it the item then update the firestore database with the item address.

I am using google maps API to get the address of each item.

What is the best way to loop over the list and for each item i want to get the address and update the database before the next item.

How to perform sequential functions in forEach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean that? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: I can't see any addresses in your array. Do you want to look them up somewhere?

Comment: I want to add the addresses to the items through google maps api

Answer (score 1):

Use geocode api of google maps, that should give you the address

```
this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=your_api_key')
   .subscribe((getplaceData) => {

          let address = { address: getplaceData['results'][0].formatted_address, coords: data};

        }, err => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

Since you have an array of coordinates, I will use Rxjs forkJoin

```
const arrayOfCalls = [];
place.forEach(pl => {
arrayOfCalls.push(
 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + pl.lat + ',' + pl.lng + '&key=your_api_key'
 )
})

forkJoin(ArrayOfCalls).subscribe((data)=> {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Many Thanks for your kind help

Comment: But it gave me punch ofQ